# Using ngx-print to print ngx-qrcode

Tags: angular

as I say in the title, I'm trying to print a QR Code through ngx-print. However, the image doesn't appear.
[image: the image doesn't appear]

This is the code that I am using:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div id="print-section">
        <ngx-qrcode [elementType]="elementType" [value] = "[value, idEquipo]" cssClass = "aclass" errorCorrectionLevel = "L"></ngx-qrcode>
    </div>
    <button printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to point out that elementType is a Canvas.

Comment: reason is elementType, it works with url

Comment: Thanks! That worked!